# Form background image change -> picture box show changes later

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with pictureboxes. I'm creating game launcher and when I click on picturebox (in the role of button) I want to change Form background image to different image. It's OK but picturebox has got transparent background color, so the background of picture box depends on Form bg image. And here is my problem - the background of picturebox changes later than Form bg img.

How can I solve this problem?

Before click: http://postimg.org/image/pubpcm6wd/
Interphase(problem): http://postimg.org/image/zf4fa97hj/ (I can see it only few milliseconds)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace posteruslauncher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            domu.Visible = false;
        }
        //Pohyb okna
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
        public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
        public const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
        public const int HTCAPTION = 0x0002;

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Po kliknutí možno hýbat s launcherem
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE + HTCAPTION, 0);
        }
        //DOMŮ - BUTTON
        private void domu_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                domu.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.domu2));

        }

        private void domu_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                domu.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.domu1;

        }

        private void domu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             novinky.Visible = true;

            domu_clicked.Visible = true;
            domu.Visible = false;
            this.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.background;

        }
        // NOVINKY - BUTTON
        private void novinky_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            novinky.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.novinky2;
        }

        private void novinky_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            novinky.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.novinky1;
        }

        private void novinky_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            domu.Visible = true;
            domu_clicked.Visible = false;
            novinky.Visible = false;
            this.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.background_novinky;



        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, we probably need to see your code. :)

Comment: Off the top of my head, your code doesn't seem to be the issue. Hopefully you can get an answer on this, I would be curious to know what the cause is at least.

Comment: How many buttons(pictureboxes) do you have? Why are you making some visibles and some not? In your images you need to point where these buttons are.

Comment: I have four pictureboxes (domu, domu_clicked, novinky, novinky_clicked) domu_clicked is below domu and novinky_clicked is below novinky. Im making it visible because after click I want to switch on picturebox. But here isnt problem, because same problem is with one picturebox, I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() to temporarily suspend the layout from drawing itself. I'm unsure what your language is, but here is an example:

```
private void novinky_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();

        domu.Visible = true;
        domu_clicked.Visible = false;
        novinky.Visible = false;
        this.BackgroundImage = posteruslauncher.Properties.Resources.background_novinky;

        this.ResumeLayout();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have still the same problem.

Comment: May I ask the reason you're using ReleaseCapture and SendMessage? Try removing those and see if that is the issue.

Comment: Its because I want to move with my launcher when mouse is down. But I tried to delete it, and my problem is still unresolved.